# Moralis and Thirdweb

Tags: moralis, thirdweb

I’m building the Open-sea Dapp to practice myself. I’m just wonder if I can use Moralis and Thirdweb with each other. Is it possible? I’m connecting MetaMask with Moralis and I would like to have another page that contains the Collections that I have in Thirdweb.

Answer (score 1):

GM there!

That should be possible, but seems like Moralis' functionality is overlapping a lot w/ Thirdweb, recommend that you choose either one

However, if you use our new Moralis 2.0 now we're backend focus and only provide you with APIs to index the blockchain, so that way you can just have Thirdweb used for interaction with the smart contracts

Let me know if you are not clear with this

Cheers~